# Experiences with single-instance multi-tenant web application in Seam?

Tags: seam, saas, multi-tenant

Any experiences with Seam in a one-instance multi-tenant setup? Is Seam suited for that setup? How did you realise it? What were the costs involved?

Our situation: A Seam 2.1 SaaS web-app (POJO, no EJB). Available development budget forced us towards a simplistic one-instance per tenant design. The application is not in production yet but nearly finished.

I expect our customer might reconsider a one-instance multi-tenant setup if it lowers the projected hosting costs.

Answer (score 2):

We've developed a multi-tenant SaaS application with Seam. I don't think that Seam has any advantages or disadvantages for this sort of thing.

The only piece of functionality that is possibly useful are Hibernate Filters (eg. have a company id on every table and set a hibernate filter for it). Means every query will have this ID automatically appended.

Answer (score 0):

I have a class called User, and it has as it's members all of that users data.  So, there's a one to many relationship from User to Task, for instance.  Then my query for all of a users tasks is simply: `select task from Task task, User user where user.id = #{user.id} and task member of user.taskList`.  I could also have used filters as another has mentioned.  However, since the #{user} object is created on log in, it's available via Seams parsing of the EL string.  Quite handy.
So, while there is nothing in Seam to support multi-tenant, it's fairly easy to do.